# Login horks from Localhost but not from server

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login

I have made a script, following sdk examples, that gets me a login button if i am not logged in or a log out if i am. While i was developing it on localhost everything worked fine, now that i have moved to a host (freehostia.com) clicking log in gets me logged in, but $user = $facebook->getUser(); somehow returns 0 (i now it gets me logged in as if i open facebook in another tab i am logged in) and i get a link that has code=xxxxxxx&state=xxxxx#*=*  . Error_log has not helped cause nothing gets logged. Can someone help?

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => $appid,
 'secret' => $appsecret,
 'cookie' => false,
 ));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$me=null;
echo $user;
 if ($user) {
 try {
    $me=$facebook->api('/me');
    $facebook->api('/me/feed','post', array(
        'message'=>'kalimera!'
    ));
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e)
    {
    error_log($e); 
    $user=null;
}
}
if ($me)
{
    $logoutUrl=$facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    echo "<a href='$logoutUrl'>Logout</a>";
}
else
{
    $loginUrl=$facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope'=>'publish_stream,read_friendlists'
    ));
    echo "<a href='$loginUrl'>Login</a>";
}
```

Also i have enabled curl on php and i have set a path for session as session.save_path = "/"

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: my code is mostly the example :

Comment: $facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => $appid,
 'secret' => $appsecret,
 'cookie' => false,
 ));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$me=null;
echo $user;
 if ($user) {
 try {
    $me=$facebook->api('/me');
 $facebook->api('/me/feed','post', array(
  'message'=>'kalimera!'
  ));
 }
 catch (FacebookApiException $e)
 {
  error_log($e); 
  $user=null;
 }
}
if ($me)
{
 $logoutUrl=$facebook->getLogoutUrl();
 echo "<a href='$logoutUrl'>Logout</a>";
}
else
{
 $loginUrl=$facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
  'scope'=>'publish_stream,read_friendlists'
 ));
 echo "<a href='$loginUrl'>Login</a>";
}

Comment: Oh please, don't post code in comments, but edit your question.